# When and how to check Python subclasses meet specification

Tags: python, oop, verification

I have a base class that looks something like this:

```
class myBaseClass:
   def __init__(self):
      self.name = None     # All subclasses must define this
   def foo(self):          # All subclasses must define this
      raise NotImplementedError
   def bar(self):          # Optional -- not all subclasses will define this 
      raise NotImplementedError
```

My API specification stipulates that anyone creating a subclass of `myBaseClass` must provide a meaningful value for `.name`, and for the function `.foo()`. However, `.bar()` is optional and calling code should be able to handle the case where that results in a `NotImplementedError`.

When and how should I check that subclasses contributed by third parties meet these requirements?

The options seem to be:

- Build subclasses exclusively via metaclasses. However, this approach will be unfamiliar and potentially confusing to most of the contributors to my project, who tend not to be expert developers.
- Add an `__init_subclass__` method to the base class and use this to infer whether the subclass has overridden everything it is supposed to override. Seems to work, but feels a bit 'kludgy'.
- Write build-time tests to instantiate each subclass, call each 'required' method, and verify that they do not raise a NotImplementedError. Seems like an excessive computational effort to answer such a simple question (calling `.foo()` may be expensive).
- Ignore the issue. Deal with it if and when it causes something else to break.

I'm sure I'm not the only person who needs to deal with this issue - is there a 'correct' approach here?

Comment: If `bar` is optional, it probably shouldn't be part of this class at all.

Comment: Can `bar` return a default/have a default functionality besides raising `NotImplementedError`? Also, is making `name` a required positional parameter for the `__init__` constructor not an option? You are right that metaclasses/ABC would be the best approach. Since you can't go that route, you will most likely have to introduce some code  into the init method that asserts/checks for the correct functionality or presence of methods & attributes

Comment: Look at ABC (Abstract Base Class)

Comment: What do you consider "a meaningful value"?

Comment: @Sparrow1029 Yes, `name` probably does belong in the constructor. As for `bar()`: this function implements an operation that only exists for a subset of cases. I guess one could have a default return value of `None` or somesuch, but catching an exception seems more pythonic.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi For present purposes, let's say 'meaningful value' is 'any non-empty string'. Obviously the code here is a cut-down toy example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would structure it.

First off, what you're looking for here is an abstract base class. Using the built-in modules you can easily define it as such and have methods be forced to have an implementation, otherwise the class will raise an exception when instantiated.

If the name attribute needs to be set always, then you should make it part of the constructor arguments.

Because `bar` is not always required I wouldn't define it as a method in the base class you have. Instead I would make a child class that is also abstract and define it there as required. When checking to see if the method is available you can use `isinstance`.

This is what my final code would look like:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class FooBaseClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        """Some useful docs for foo"""


class FooBarBaseClass(FooBaseClass, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        """Some useful docs for bar"""
```

When creating instances you can pick the base class you want and will be forced to define the methods.

```
class FooClass(FooBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("foo")

    def foo(self):
        print("Calling foo from FooClass")


class FooBarClass(FooBarBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("foobar")

    def foo(self):
        print("Calling foo from FooBarClass")

    def bar(self):
        print("Calling bar from FooBarClass")
```

Example checking if bar is callable:

```
def do_operation(obj: FooBaseClass):
    obj.foo()
    if isinstance(obj, FooBarBaseClass):
        obj.bar()
```

Example:

```
do_operation(FooClass())
do_operation(FooBarClass())
```

```
Calling foo from FooClass
Calling foo from FooBarClass
Calling bar from FooBarClass
```

An example of invalid code

```
class InvalidClass(FooBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("foo")

InvalidClass()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\so\test.py", line 52, in <module>
    InvalidClass()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class InvalidClass with abstract method foo
```